# Given File Path, Open in File Explorer (Windows) or Finder (Mac) with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

From a Django web application, given a file path from the user, how do I "Show in Explorer" or "Reveal in Finder".

For example, if I have /path/to/file/on/user/computer, I would want when a user clicked a button for a File Explorer or Finder window to pop open that would locate/reveal the file.

Also, I do not want the file to be opened in the browser.

Thanks you! Your future feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening local files directly is typically considered a security restriction

From how the question is formulated, there are several options available but depends on what your use case is

If all you need to do is prevent the file from being open by the browser (typically the case with PDFs) and force a download instead, you can use the `Content-Disposition: attachment` HTTP header

If you're really after opening Finder or Explorer, you can still register a custom protocol handler and some instructions for the users (unless you're the only user of that app).

Comment: Thanks. So, there is no way to just show the file highlighted in file explorer or finder?

Comment: no, not in a consistent, cross-browser fashion. sorry